# Regular expression for comments that begin and end on different lines

Tags: java, regex

Okay, so I've been working on this problem for a couple of weeks now where I have a program that reads a file that contains some code from a mini language, read and then print each token with a description of what the token is. Part of this mini language is its ability to support single-line and multi-line comments.

The regular expression for comments are `\{[^\}]*\}` meaning:

- A comment begins with an open curly brace `\{`
- Followed by 0 or more of any character except a closing curly brace `[^\}]*`
- Followed by a closing curly brace, which ends the comment `\}`

**Side Note:** Comments cannot be nested, meaning that if I have a comment such as `{This is a {nested} comment}` would not be considered a valid comment because it can only have one closing curly brace. That being said, however, a comment such as `{This is another {comment}` would be valid since there is only one closing curly brace

While testing this program out, I ran into an issue where my program would read in a file and come across a multi-line comment, but instead of the program being able to recognize the comment as multi-lined, it just prints out what's inside of the comment, rather than the whole comment itself. I've spent a good week or week and a half on trying to get this to work. I've tried various combinations of regular expressions and where I place my `if` statements, but to come to no solution. I've tried everything I can to fix it but since I'm not very experienced with regular expressions I must be missing something pretty obvious.

Here I have a snippet of my code
**Side Note:** I have my program take in the name of the file through user input in another class.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;    

public class Analyzer {

    public void lex(String filename) {

        try {

            Scanner scanFile = new Scanner(file);

            while(scanFile.hasNextLine()) {

                String str = scanFile.nextLine();

                String keyword = "(\\bWHILE\\b|\\bENDWHILE\\b|\\bIF\\b|\\bENDIF\\b|\\bPRINT\\b)";
                String comment = "(\\{[^\\}]*\\})";
                String literal = "(\\b[0-9]+\\b)";
                String identifier = "(\\b[a-z]+\\b)";
                String symbol = "((\\()|(\\))|(;))";
                String operator = "((\\+)|(\\-)|(\\*)|(/)|(\\=)|(\\<)|(\\:\\=))";

                String keywordERROR = "(PRINT\\w+)";
                String commentERROR = "(\\{.*\\}.*\\})";
                String literalERROR = "([0-9]+[a-zA-Z_]+)";
                String identERROR = "([a-z]+[A-Z_0-9]+)";
                String alphabetERROR = "(~|`|\\!|@|#|\\$|%|\\^|\\&|_|\\||\\:|'|\"|\\?|\\>|\\.|\\,|\\\\)";

                String regex = keyword + "|" + keywordERROR + "|" + comment + "|" + commentERROR + "|" + literal + "|" + literalERROR
                    + "|" + identifier + "|" + identERROR + "|" + symbol + "|" + operator + "|" + alphabetERROR;

                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

                while(matcher.find()) {

                    if(matcher.group(1) != null)
                        System.out.println(matcher.group(1) + "\tKeyword");
                    else if(matcher.group(2) != null)
                        System.out.println(matcher.group(2) + "\tError");

                    if(matcher.group(3) != null)
                        System.out.println(matcher.group(3) + "\tComment");
                    else if(matcher.group(4) != null)
                        System.out.println(matcher.group(4) + "\tError");

                    if(matcher.group(5) != null)
                        System.out.println(matcher.group(5) + "\tLiteral");
                    else if(matcher.group(6) != null)
                        System.out.println(matcher.group(6) + "\tError");

                    if(matcher.group(7) != null)
                        System.out.println(matcher.group(7) + "\tIdentifier");
                    else if(matcher.group(8) != null)
                        System.out.println(matcher.group(8) + "\tError");

                    if(matcher.group(9) != null) {
                        if(matcher.group(10) != null)
                            System.out.println(matcher.group(10) + "\tOpen Parenthesis");
                        if(matcher.group(11) != null)
                            System.out.println(matcher.group(11) + "\tClose Parenthesis");
                        if(matcher.group(12) != null)
                            System.out.println(matcher.group(12) + "\tSemi-colon");
                    }

                    if(matcher.group(13) != null) {
                        if(matcher.group(14) != null)
                            System.out.println(matcher.group(14) + "\tAddition Operator");
                        if(matcher.group(15) != null)
                            System.out.println(matcher.group(15) + "\tSubtraction Operator");
                        if(matcher.group(16) != null)
                            System.out.println(matcher.group(16) + "\tMultiplication Operator");
                        if(matcher.group(17) != null)
                            System.out.println(matcher.group(17) + "\tDivision Operator");
                        if(matcher.group(18) != null)
                            System.out.println(matcher.group(18) + "\tEquality Comparison Operator");
                        if(matcher.group(19) != null)
                            System.out.println(matcher.group(19) + "\tLess Than Operator");
                        if(matcher.group(20) != null)
                            System.out.println(matcher.group(20) + "\tAssignment Operator");
                    }

                    if(matcher.group(21) != null) 
                        System.out.println(matcher.group(21) + "\tError");
                }
            }

            scanFile.close();

        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Like I said before, I've tried many different ways on trying to solve for this issue. Some of the things I've tried were adding the return sequences like this: `\{[^\}]*[\r\n]*\}`, `\{[\r\n]*[^\}]*\}`, `\{[\r\n]*[^\}]*[\r\n]*\}`, `\{[^\}]*\s*\}`, `\{\s*[^\}]*\s*\}`, `(?s)\{[^\}]*\}` and `(?m)\{[^\}]*\}`, trying the `DOTALL` and `MULTILINE` flags for my Pattern object, and just looking for any tutorial I could find to use but I haven't had any luck.

The file that I'm reading from looks like this:

```
{This is
a multi-line
comment.}
WHILE(x<10)
    PRINT x;
    x:=x+2;
ENDWHILE
```

The output should look like this:

```
{This is a multi-line comment}    Comment
WHILE    Keyword
(    Open Parenthesis
x    Identifier
<    Less Than Operator
10   Literal
)    Close Parenthesis
PRINT    Keyword
x    Identifier
;    Semi-colon
x    Identifier
:=   Assignment Operator
x    Identifier
+    Addition Operator
2    Literal
;    Semi-colon
ENDWHILE    Keyword
```

But instead the output looks like this:

```
is  Identifier
a   Identifier
multi   Identifier
-   Subtraction Operator
line    Identifier
comment Identifier
.   Error
WHILE   Keyword
(   Open Parenthesis
x   Identifier
<   Less Than Operator
10  Literal
)   Close Parenthesis
PRINT   Keyword
x   Identifier
;   Semi-colon
x   Identifier
:=  Assignment Operator
x   Identifier
+   Addition Operator
2   Literal
;   Semi-colon
ENDWHILE    Keyword
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You're using the wrong tool for the job. If you're parsing program text you should be using a scanner and a parser. Regular expressions are not sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just continue reading the file with another **while** loop IF your line starts with a open curly brace but doesn't end with a close curly brace, something like this:

```
while(scanFile.hasNextLine()) {
    String str = scanFile.nextLine().trim();  // trim off indents etc.

    // If the line is blank just read in the next line.
    if (str.equals("")) { continue; }

    // If this is a multi-line comment then
    if (str.startsWith("{") && !str.endsWith("}")) { 
        while(scanFile.hasNextLine()) {
            String commentStr = scanFile.nextLine().trim();
            str+= " " + commentStr;
            if (commentStr.endsWith("}")) { break; }
        }
    }

    // Do the rest of your processing....
    // ..................................
    // ..................................
}
```

On another note....I wouldn't use RegEx to parse this file content but perhaps you need to for some reason. Good RegEx exercise in any case. :)

Answer (score 0):

The code doesn't work because Java's `Pattern` (used for regex) has [`MULTILINE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#MULTILINE) mode disabled by default.

Try enabling it using `(?m)` at the start of the regex string. Or otherwise setting the `Pattern`'s configuration to use MULTILINE.

AFAICS there is nothing (else) wrong with the `\{[^\}]*\}` regex, although you could probably use `\{.*?\}` instead, which is slightly more readable.